# Warning: Attempt to read property "[ARRAY KEY]" on null in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

```
$pairs      = [];                                   // Clear the pairs array
$pairs['post_name'] = $post->post_name;             // Hold the post_name for the error function's use
$pairs['post_id'] = $post->ID;                      // Hold the post ID for the error function's use
$pairs['tag'] = $tag;                               // Add the tag to the pairs array for the error function's use
```

The above is code to define an array then set a few values. This is throwing an error that I suspect is complaining because I didn't pre-define the keys, but I also don't want to. One of the biggest advantages of PHP is that it's not necessary to pre-define and allocate every little thing when it's obvious from context.

Is there a simple way of solving this problem without having to predefine the entire array and all it's keys? I tried changing the definition to $pairs = {} on the hopes it would be happier, but no dice. I suspect this is a problem with updating to PHP 8 and am tempted to turn off warnings, but would rather do it "right" (unless that means predefining everything).

EDIT: TO be clear, the error listed in the title applies to ALL of the above assignments and any other similar assignments in my code. I'm getting a hundred or more instances of this error because I've always created array keys on assignment like this before and I'd like to keep doing so.

Comment: Please post more code and full error with line number

Comment: The errors is about property of object $post and not array, if it null you will get errors like that. So, what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: For array related errors, You will get 'Undefined index' error. So your must be related to the object `post`

Comment: @taras - I want it to set the $pairs[index] value to what I listed. I want to be able to add any new index at any time by using an assignment as shown.

Comment: You really need to learn how to do debugging. (Because the problem is not in assigning `$pairs['post_name']` with a value)

Comment: The code you have shown is valid assuming `$post` is an object containings theses properties. What you're describing is perfectly valid in PHP. What we are saying is that `$post` is `null` and therefore, you're getting `Attempt to read property "post_name" on null`

Comment: @Clement, so the right-hand var is what's null? Ok, I'm still having the assignment problem so I'll need to make a new post with other examples. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: reproduced with `$post` set to `null` and getting the same errors: https://3v4l.org/q4BA3 Proof it works when `$post` is set with the properties: https://3v4l.org/svr5F